# Get all attributes from table td as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I hava a table with checkboxes inside `td` with `id=td1`.

I would like to get attributes `data-ref` as javascript `array` from all checked `checkboxes`.

Something like:

```
[{"data-ref": "test1"}, {"date-ref": "test2"}, ... ]
```

It will also be enough if I can just get `data-ref` values, like:

```
['test1', 'test2', ...]
```

Checked `checkboxes` I can get with:

```
$('#tableUSNW tbody tr td :checked');
```

How to get all attributes data-ref as array? Is there some easier way than writing `each()` function from `jQuery`?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableUSNW">
<thead>
<th id="th1">Stolpec 1</th>
  <th id="th2">Stolpec 2</th>
  <th id="th3">Stolpec 3</th>
    </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="tr1" data-userkey="test1"><td id="td1" data-ref="test1"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr2" data-userkey="test2"><td id="td1" data-ref="test2"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr3" data-userkey="test3"><td id="td1" data-ref="test3"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr4" data-userkey="test4"><td id="td1" data-ref="test4"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr5" data-userkey="test5"><td id="td1" data-ref="test5"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  
  
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: ["data-ref": "test1", "date-ref": "test2", ... ] is invalid

Comment: javascript array is not like php array, as kevin said what you want is invalid, but you can have object like this: `{"data-ref": "test1", "date-ref": "test2", ... }`, pretty much the same as array, but its not ordered, or you can have array like this [test1, test2 ...], that is ordered.

Comment: also note, id MUST be unique, so you can't have the same id in 2 or more elements, put them as class.

Comment: And your HTML code is also invalid. You can't have multiple elements having the same ID. ID should be unique within the DOM.

Comment: there's no sense to get those attributes as an array of objects with the same key name. It's enough to get all `data-ref` values like `['test1', 'test2' ...]`

Comment: @Roman - that's ok - how to get those values?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way, using jQuery's `each`

*I also cleaned up the markup a little when it comes to `id`'s, as they are supposed to be unique*

```js
var checked_datarefs = [];

$("#view").click(function() {

  $("#tableUSNW input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function(index) {
    
    checked_datarefs.push($(this).closest('td').data('ref'));    
    
  });

  console.log(checked_datarefs);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableUSNW">
  <thead>
    <th id="th1">Stolpec 1</th>
    <th id="th2">Stolpec 2</th>
    <th id="th3">Stolpec 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-userkey="test1">
      <td id="td11" data-ref="test1">
        <input id="inputChk1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="td13">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-userkey="test2">
      <td id="td21" data-ref="test2">
        <input id="inputChk2" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="td23">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-userkey="test3">
      <td id="td31" data-ref="test3">
        <input id="inputChk3" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="td33">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-userkey="test4">
      <td id="td41" data-ref="test4">
        <input id="inputChk4" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="td43">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-userkey="test5">
      <td id="td51" data-ref="test5">
        <input id="inputChk5" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="td53">test3</td>
    </tr>


    <tbody>
</table>

<button id="view">Checked</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using any loop, you can manipulate the list of `data-ref` attributes of all checked checkboxes dynamically.
The solution using `Set` object:

```js
var dataRefs = new Set();
$("#tableUSNW input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function(){
  var ref = $(this).parent().data('ref');
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    dataRefs.add(ref);
  } else {
    dataRefs.delete(ref);
  }
  
});

$('.showRefList').on('click', function(){
  alert(Array.from(dataRefs));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableUSNW">
<thead>
<th id="th1">Stolpec 1</th>
  <th id="th2">Stolpec 2</th>
  <th id="th3">Stolpec 3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr id="tr1" data-userkey="test1"><td id="td1" data-ref="test1"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr2" data-userkey="test2"><td id="td1" data-ref="test2"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr3" data-userkey="test3"><td id="td1" data-ref="test3"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr4" data-userkey="test4"><td id="td1" data-ref="test4"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tr id="tr5" data-userkey="test5"><td id="td1" data-ref="test5"><input id="inputChk" type="checkbox"></td><td>test2</td><td id="td3">test3</td></tr>
  <tbody>
</table>
<button class='showRefList'>Show data-ref list</button>
```

Of course, you can easily store an array of `data-ref` attributes(`Array.from(dataRefs)`) in a predefined variable.

Comment: Why do you use dat('ref') instead of .attr('data-ref'). Is there any benefit using data() instead of attr() ?

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

I forgot to add the removal of a `data-ref` value from the array `refArray`:

> ```
> else {
>  refArray.pop.(ref);
> }
> ```

As OP requested, the following Snippet does not use `.each()`. The function's purpose is to gather the value of the attribute `data-ref` of each `<td>` that is a parent of a checked checkbox, then return the results in an array.

Although not relevant to the question, but worthy to mention is the use of the id attribute, we must always insure that each one is unique on the page. So in the Snippet, the duplicate ids have been corrected.

Details are commented in the Snippet:

#### SNIPPET

```js
/* Create an empty array */
var refArray = [];
/* Any change event on any checkbox
|  will trigger the function
*/
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  /* $(this) refers to the function owner, in
  |  this case it is the specific checked checkbox
  */
  /* The checked checkbox's parent's data-ref */
  var ref = $(this).parent('td').data('ref');

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    /* Add data-ref value to refArray */
    refArray.push(ref);
  } else {
    /* Remove data-ref value from refArray */
    refArray.pop(ref);
  }
  console.log(refArray);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tableUSNW">
  <thead>
    <th id="th1">Stolpec 1</th>
    <th id="th2">Stolpec 2</th>
    <th id="th3">Stolpec 3</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="trA" data-userkey="test1">
      <td id="tdA1" data-ref="test1">
        <input id="chx1" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="tdA3">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trB" data-userkey="test2">
      <td id="tdB1" data-ref="test2">
        <input id="chx2" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="tdB3">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trC" data-userkey="test3">
      <td id="tdC1" data-ref="test3">
        <input id="chx3" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="tdC3">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trD" data-userkey="test4">
      <td id="tdD1" data-ref="test4">
        <input id="chx4" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="tdD3">test3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="trE" data-userkey="test5">
      <td id="tdE1" data-ref="test5">
        <input id="chx5" type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>test2</td>
      <td id="tdE3">test3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I've noticed one thing: you are using function data('ref') for accessing data-ref attribute. Is there a reason you don't use .attr('data-ref')?

Comment: One more question: if every row has unique attribute, like id or some other attribute - isn't in this case every cell inside that row unique, even if theirs attributes are repeated in rows? Ex: <tr id='unique1'><td id='td1'></td></tr> <tr id='unique2'><td id='td1'></td></tr> -- id td1 is unique inside each row. Only the search must be like that $('tr[id=unique1] td[id=td1]')

Comment: In this case, `.attr()` and `.data()`, it wouldn't make much of a difference. The big difference between them is that the value that you give a key while using `.data()` will convert a string into it's implied type. So if `data-ref='3'` would actually be a number 3, while with `.attr()`, it's a string "3".

Comment: `id`s are always unique and it confuses the browser's parser in unpredictable ways. In CSS, an `#id` has a large selectivity (calculated priority in CSS), which I believe would work exactly as you describe. With JavaScript/jQuery, an `#id` will most likely be accepted only once and ignored if encountered any other time while parsing. That is just one reason that may or may not apply, since browsers handle parsing with slightly to completely different algorithms for different situations. But `id`s uniqueness is paramount importance if you desire consistency.

Comment: What if I use some different attribute other than id, for the same reason? Let's say instead of id I use data-my-id, with same values as before for id.

Comment: That would be completely valid, sir. The best alternative is `class`, or `data-*` if you intend to carry some arbitrary values along.

Comment: I have just one more question: is it important that attribute name is like data-* ? Or it can be anything, like test-first, test-second ... ?

Comment: There is specific syntax involving `data-*`. It must be prefixed like so: `data-`. It must be  lowercase. Under certain circumstances, it must be camel case. ex. `data-user-id` would be `dataUserId`.  For details see [Using Data Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) and [jQuery Data](http://api.jquery.com/category/data/)

Comment: BTW, I just updated the function so that if a checkbox is unchecked, the array would remove the corresponding value.